# Running multiple jobs in spark

Tags: linux, scala, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a script (script1.sh) that runs a spark job which takes in two parameters a and b .
  The same script access different resources if I change the parameters to c and d .
  This script is used to run a job on the spark cluster .

Currently the job is being run at two differnet times 1st is at 10:00am and the second is at 11:00am :

```
     $ sh -x script1.sh a b
     $ sh -x script1.sh c d
```

I know we can run multiple scripts simultaneously using :

```
    $ sh -x script1.sh & sh -x script2.sh & sh -x script3.sh
```

but I dont have multiple scripts .

I am not too concerned about performance for now

What is the most efficient way for me to run both the modules simultaneously ? 
  Can I do :

```
      $ sh -x script1.sh a b & sh -x script1.sh c d
```

is there a more efficient way ? Would I need to change anything here ?
  These are the current specs :

```
      --driver-memory 15G \
      --driver-cores 5 \
      --num-executors 30 \
      --executor-memory 20G \
      --executor-cores 5 \
```

P.S:I would much rather not edit the shell script .

Comment: I used this  $ sh -x script1.sh a b & sh -x script1.sh c d  and the second job failed

Comment: `sh -x script1.sh a b & sh -x script1.sh c d` should work unless the script uses some resource that cannot be accessed concurrently. What is the error message of the failure?

Comment: @qan99 , what is the error message you are receiving ??

Comment: if simultanous execution fails, then run `sh -x script1.sh a b && sh -x script1.sh c d `

Comment: Thanks . The error was because I was trying to access something through a different module for which the application didnt have access to . It worked when I tried with a different module .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your command will run both `sh` commands simultaneously. You can check with a simple example, e.g. `sleep.sh` contains `sleep $1` and running
`sh -x sleep.sh 2 & sh -x sleep.sh 3` results in both commands finishing after approximately 3 seconds.

Whether or not the scripts will complete in the maximum time it takes to complete one of them, depends on the resources of the cluster.